# Objective C - How to communicate with OS X's Bluetooth USB Host Controller

Tags: objective-c, macos, bluetooth, iokit

I am currently programming a Bluetooth Communication framework in Objective C and this projects special ability is that it communicates directly with the Apple Bluetooth Controller. OS X Treats the Bluetooth Module as a USB Device and so far i have managed to access it through the `IOKit` Framework and also using 
`sudo kextunload -b com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport`

to release the Systems ownership of the controller. I have also managed to read and send NSData to the controller through its interfaces and pipes.

My Question is there any documentation somewhere so i can learn how to communicate with the controller (in hexadecimal) like scan, pair, connect etc... (Kinda hopin for a one for dummies, I feel that i am pretty skilled with programming and stuff but i am pretty new to bluetooth modules, let a lone USBs)

I have been searching the internet for ages but im not exactly sure what to search for.

(Im using Apple's built in Bluetooth USB Host Controller)

[Apple Bluetooth USB Host Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWyMz.png)

Look I know I can just use the `IOBluetooth` and `CoreBluetooth` framework for handling bluetooth devices but I want to try and do this directly through the main controller to gain access to functions that OS X doesn't include (Hoping to make something like a bluetooth sniffer or whatever)

[(Program Running)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaGw9.png)

Just incase your wondering, I got the idea from VirtualBox and how it claims the Bluetooth controller and connects it to the Virtual Machine to use at will. (I know virtual machines know how to use it because they have bluetooth handling built into there operating systems)

Thanks in Advance! :D

Comment: I know this question is pretty old but I'm trying to do a similar thing, except I'm trying to interact with the host controller for an external bluetooth chip. I've just started reversing the `IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport` kext and I see there's a method `SendHCIRequest` that I am guessing is used for transmitting to the hc but I don't know how to receive. Have you made any more progress since this was posted?

Comment: Hey look sorry but I just kinda gave up on this one. Anyways Good luck, I hope you find the answer. (BTW This is my other account)